# Manipulate windows files with linux bash shell in windows 10

Tags: linux, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to manipulate windows files with newly introduced linux bash shell in windows 10. Suppose I want to copy a file from one directory to another, is there any way to mount these drives so I can manipulate files.

Comment: Are the drives not located in the /mnt directory of your system?\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there any way to mount these drives so I can manipulate files?

The following command will list your mounted drives:

```
ls /mnt
```

Your drives should (mostly) already be mounted. Note there are some restrictions:

> In order for a drive to show up under /mnt/ it must meet the following
>   criteria:
>
> 1. The drive must be a fixed drive
> 2. The drive must be formatted to NTFS.

This means that optical disc drives, network mounted drives and some USB drives  will **not** be mounted under the Windows Linux Subsystem.

This has been raised as an issue: [Drives other than C: are not mounted in /mnt #1079](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1079). It is still marked as "Open".

> To facilitate interoperability with Windows, WSL uses the DrvFs file system. WSL automatically mounts all fixed drives with supported file systems under /mnt, such as /mnt/c, /mnt/d, etc. Currently, only NTFS and ReFS volumes are supported.

Source [WSL File System Support](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/06/15/wsl-file-system-support/)

---

#### Further Reading

- [WSL File System Support](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/06/15/wsl-file-system-support/)

Answer (score -1):

Run the command:

```
sudo mount -t drvfs E: /mnt/e
```

Reference: https://techobia.com/mounting-usb-flash-storage-devices-inside-windows-inbuilt-linux-bash/